# ModX tvFilter wildcards returning unwanted queries

Tags: modx

i've been scratching my head on this for so long, im hoping someone could point out what im doing wrong...and that im explaining clearly...

I have a listBox (Multi-select) TV called "Country" with the following option values:

Global||US||Australia||French||German||Spanish||Portuguese||UK

On my resources, i have them tagged with whatever country is relevant for the resource. Some has only 1 tag, some has 2.

When i query for these resources using getResources and with this parameter: &tvFilters=`country==%US%||country==%Global%` , the expectation is that i get back all resources with either of those tags. But the reality is that, i also get resources tagged as Australia as well, due to the wildcard. Removing the wildcards wont work correctly as there are some resources with 2 tags.

How can i get this to not return Australia resources?

version:
ModX Revolution 2.3.3

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because of `aUStralia` and `%`. Change `US` to `United States` or something else and try again.

Comment: Thank you, i havent had a chance to test this out yet, but this makes perfect sense and is probably the only solution.